# Calling Stored Procedures in Spring - Synchronous vs Asynchronous

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I've developed an application leveraging Spring's org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure to execute an Oracle stored procedure.  I'm calling the procedure in my Java method and then using Hibernate mapped entities later in the method to pull data out of tables that the procedure populates.  The problem I'm facing is that sometimes the data appears to be populated and other times it does not.  I've debugged extensively and I cannot find a reason why this would happen, so I'm starting to wonder if stored procedure calls in Spring are synchronous or asynchronous?  Perhaps the stored procedure isn't finished before the code that follows this call is executed and therefore providing me an NPE?

So my question is this: is there a way to control whether store procedure calls through Spring are synchronous or asynchronous?  I poked around online but wasn't able to find this information.

Thanks for reading!